# Nested DataList and item command of a nested Datalist in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I have nested DataList as 'DataList1' with in another datalist 'dl1' , when I am trying to fire an event on linkbutton click which is in 'dl1' it is not firing, and it is working for the second click. Using break point I checked the code, datalist 'DataList1' is binding in the first click, but not displaying it.

Can anyone please help with your suggestions,... I cant get it through many searches..

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what is `dl1` ? is it `DataList1` ?

Comment: yes dl1 is a parent datalist and DataList1 is a child or nested datalist in dl1